# Setting mongodb editor path in .mongorc on mac

Tags: mongodb, macos

I'm trying to set the path to visual studio code text editor for mongodb in the **.mongorc.js** on mac so I add this line to .mongorc.js ...

```
EDITOR="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app"
```

in terminal

```
$ edit whateverTheVarName
```

this is the output

```
please define EDITOR as a JavaScript string or as an environment variable
```

Im assuming didn't wright the EDITOR="" path correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> EDITOR="/Applications/Visual\\ Studio\\
>   Code.app/Contents/MacOS/[program name]"

that would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

For visual studio code do this

EDITOR="/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron"

(also make sure your **.mongorc.js** file is located in **/Users/yourUsername** folder)

Comment: You need double backslashes (like @Euclides) for this to work, but otherwise this does the job!